# Binding with StringFormat on a custom control

Tags: c#, wpf, string-formatting, templatebinding

I'm trying to use a custom control in a WPF app, and I have some problem using a StringFormat binding.

The problem is easy to reproduce. First, let's create a WPF application and call it "TemplateBindingTest". There, add a custom ViewModel with only one property (Text), and assign it to the DataContext of the Window. Set the Text property to "Hello World!".

Now, add a custom control to the solution. The custom control is as simple as it can get:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace TemplateBindingTest
{
    public class CustomControl : Control
    {
        static CustomControl()
        {
            TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                "Text",
                typeof(object),
                typeof(CustomControl),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomControl)));
        }

        public static DependencyProperty TextProperty;

        public object Text
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetValue(TextProperty);
            }

            set
            {
                SetValue(TextProperty, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When adding the custom control to the solution, Visual Studio automatically created a Themes folder, with a generic.xaml file. Let's put the default style for the control in there:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TemplateBindingTest">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Now, just add the control to the window, and set a binding on the Text property, using a StringFormat. Also add a simple TextBlock to be sure that the binding syntax is correct:

```
<Window x:Class="TemplateBindingTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:TemplateBindingTest="clr-namespace:TemplateBindingTest" Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<StackPanel>
    <TemplateBindingTest:CustomControl Text="{Binding Path=Text, StringFormat=Test1: {0}}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text, StringFormat=Test2: {0}}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Compile, run, aaaaand... The text displayed on the window is:

> Hello World!
>
> Test2: Hello World!

On the custom control, the StringFormat is completely ignored. No error is visible on VS output window. What's going on?

Edit: **The workaround.**

Ok, the TemplateBinding was misleading. I found the cause and a dirty workaround.

First, notice that the problem is the same with the Content property of Button:

```
<Button Content="{Binding Path=Text, StringFormat=Test3: {0}}" />
```

So, what's going on? Let's use Reflector and dive to the StringFormat property of the BindingBase class. The 'Analyse' feature shows that this property is used by the internal `DetermineEffectiveStringFormat` method. Let's see this method:

```
internal void DetermineEffectiveStringFormat()
{
    Type propertyType = this.TargetProperty.PropertyType;
    if (propertyType == typeof(string))
    {
         // Do some checks then assign the _effectiveStringFormat field
    }
}
```

The problem is right here. The effectiveStringFormat field is the one used when resolving the Binding. And this field is assigned only if the DependencyProperty is of type `String` (mine is, as Button's Content property, `Object`).

Why Object? Because my custom control is a bit more complex than the one I pasted, and like the Button I want the control's user to be able to provide child controls rather than just text.

So, what now? We're running into a behaviour existing even in WPF core controls, so I can just leave it "as is". Still, as my custom control is used only on an internal project, and I want it to be easier to use from XAML, I decided to use this hack:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace TemplateBindingTest
{
    public class CustomControl : Control
    {
        static CustomControl()
        {
            TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                "Text",
                typeof(string),
                typeof(CustomControl),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, Callback));

            HeaderProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                "Header",
                typeof(object),
                typeof(CustomControl),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomControl)));
        }

        static void Callback(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            obj.SetValue(HeaderProperty, e.NewValue);
        }

        public static DependencyProperty TextProperty;
        public static DependencyProperty HeaderProperty;

        public object Header
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetValue(HeaderProperty);
            }

            set
            {
                SetValue(HeaderProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public string Text
        {
            set
            {
                SetValue(TextProperty, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Header` is the property used in my TemplateBinding. When a value is provided to `Text`, the StringFormat is applied since the property is of type `String`, then the value is forwarded to the `Header` property using a callback. It works, but it's really dirty:

- The `Header` and the `Text` property aren't in sync, as `Text` isn't updated when I update `Header`. I choose to provide no getter to the `Text` property to avoid some mistakes, but it can still happen if someone directly reads the value from the DependencyProperty (`GetValue(TextProperty)`).
- Unpredictable behaviour may happen if someone provides a value to both `Header` and `Text` property as one of the values will be lost.

So overall, I wouldn't recommand using this hack. Do it only if you are **really** in control of your project. If the control has even the slightest chance of being used on another project, just give up on the StringFormat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`StringFormat` is used when binding to a `string` property, while the `Text` property in your control is of type `object`, hence `StringFormat` is ignored.

Comment: Incorrect. The runtime invokes `object.ToString()` for all objects before formatting the string.

Comment: Yes, but it checks the underlying type of the dependency property before applying the StringFormat. It works if I change the type of my dp to String instead of Object.

Answer (score 6):

You can't pass StringFormat or Converter when using TemplateBinding. Here are few workarounds.

- [StringFormat in TemplateBinding](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/222611.aspx)
- [Binding, TemplateBinding and Converter](http://forums.silverlight.net/p/38430/255932.aspx)